# java thread safe :is it thread safe?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am reading java concurrency in practice.there are some problems,l can't understand.
for example,

```
package com.thread;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Set;

public class HiddenIterator {
    private final Set<Integer> set = Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet<Integer>());
    public void add(Integer i) {
        synchronized (set) {
            set.add(i);
        }
    }
    public void remove(Integer i) {
        synchronized (set) {
            set.remove(i);
        }
    }
    public void addTenThings() {
        Random random = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
            add(random.nextInt());
        }
        //Hidden Iterator!  
        System.out.println("DEBUG: added ten elements to " + set);
    }
}
```

is the programme thread safe?
if it is not, how to edit?

Comment: I find the [Java Concurrency Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html) to be a good guide.

Comment: @D.B. Not as good as JCIP...

Comment: @shmosel perhaps not but in general if someone finds one resource to be confusing or hard to understand it might be a good idea to read another. What makes sense for one person may not make sense for another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of your access to the set is thread-safe: the calls to `add` and `remove` are synchronized so they can't both run at the same time.

However, your `System.out` line at the end will call `toString` on the set while building the message, and `toString` must iterate through the set's elements.  Although you've used `synchronizedSet`, that only protects access to the individual elements — it *doesn't* keep the set unchanged during iteration.  If other threads are adding and removing elements while your `System.out` line runs, it's unpredictable what numbers will be shown in the message.  You need a `synchronized` block around that line to "freeze" the set's contents while building the message.

Note that only the *individual* `add` calls are synchronized, so it's possible for other threads to see the set "between" the individual items being added.  That means other threads might see the list with only some of the ten items.  Depending on what your program uses the list for, that may or may not be a problem.

If you need the ten elements to be added atomically, so that other threads see either all of them or none of them, you can put a `synchronized` block around the loop in the `addTenThings` method.

You don't need to use both `Collections.synchronizedSet` *and* `synchronized` blocks.  One or the other is OK.  The differences are:

- `Collections.synchronizedSet` protects *all* access to the set, so you can't forget to synchronize in a place where it's needed.  However, it can only protect individual method calls on the set.  In particular, iterating over the set leads to unpredictable results, because items can be added and removed by other threads while the loop is running.
- `synchronized` blocks can protect multiple method calls on the set so that they act as an atomic operation — but they only protect against other `synchronized` blocks, so you have to remember to use `synchronized` around all code that accesses the set.

Comment: Don't forget that `System.out.println` is going to iterate over the set via `toString` which means it should probably be synchronized also.

Comment: Oops, I hadn't noticed that.  Good catch; will edit.

Comment: This answer raises an important point. Many, including the official Javadocs in places, refer to a type with synchronized methods as "thread safe", but not always accurately. If only method synchronization exists, there usually are ways to use the type in a thread-unsafe way.

Comment: @LewBloch I've found that the docs do usually use accurate terminology and are careful to point out the limitations when they exist. (`Vector` was a surprising [exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42570655/why-doesnt-vector-document-how-to-iterate-safely).)

Answer (score 1):

Some of it is too safe, some of it not safe enough. You don't need to explicitly synchronize inside `add()` and `remove()`, because that's automatically done by the `synchronizedSet` wrapper.

However, you do need to synchronize around the `println()` statement, because when you concatenate `set`, it implicitly calls `set.toString()`, which internally iterates over its elements ("hidden iterator"), which is not safe without explicit synchronization, as explained in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedSet(java.util.Set)).